# Div same size as background image

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, image

So i have a div with a background image and i would like to make the div same size as the background image when i resize the window, so i can place some text in the center of it and i want to image to be responsive and so the div also.

my html for the image and text:

```
<div id="headerimg" class="header">
    <h1>Welcome to my website</h1>
</div>
```

and my cc for it so far:

```
#headerimg{
    background: url(http://images.huffingtonpost.com/2016-06-25-1466835058-3172856-DKCWebDesignBanner.jpg) no-repeat top center fixed;
    background-size: cover;
    width:100%;
}

.header{
    height: 700px;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 20%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
}
```

i am just using a  random image from google atm, ill replace later; but anyway.. how can i get the height to align whenever? Jquery maybe? -but im not realy familiar with jquery much...and yes, i want the div to be full width of the site all the time.

Comment: is it something you are looking to achieve? https://jsfiddle.net/sanjeevks121/koLrs1Le/

Comment: I you want the div to be full size of the site/window you can try using `vw/wh` like this: `#headerimg{
    background: url(http://images.huffingtonpost.com/2016-06-25-1466835058-3172856-DKCWebDesignBanner.jpg) no-repeat top center;
    background-size: cover;
    width:100vw;
    height: 100vh;
}`

Comment: Are you looking to maintain the aspect ratio of the div when you resize it?

Comment: Yes i want the div to resize according to the background image when i resize the window, I am using the background image, because i am trying to make a wanna be parallax effect.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would something like the following work for you:

https://jsfiddle.net/44k0320v/

I've updated your header width to use `50vw` units, your example image has an aspect ratio of arount 2:1 meaning that if you want the `div` to maintain the correct height you need to set the height to be half of the viewport width (the measurement across the width of the screen is `100vw`).

I have also updated the background image to have a size of `100%` rather than `cover` so it's width will scale with the `div`.

I've also updated the font size to also use `vw` units.

New css below:

```
#headerimg{
    background: url(http://images.huffingtonpost.com/2016-06-25-1466835058-3172856-DKCWebDesignBanner.jpg) no-repeat top center fixed;
    background-size: 100%;
}

.header{
    box-sizing: border-box;
    height: 50vw;
    width: 100%;
    margin: auto;
    padding: 10% 20%;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 3.5vw;
}
```

Comment: Yes, that is what i was looking for. But can i also make the text scale while i make the window smaller or bigger?

Comment: Yes you can, see in the CSS pasted above where I've set `font-size: 3.5vw`?

Comment: Yes, i see, but if i resize the window the text stays same size, it just alligns itself in two lines if needed.

Comment: Double check that you only have one `font-size` declaration in your CSS. `font-size: 50px` needs to be completely removed

Comment: It is the only font-size in whole css file.

Comment: In that case I would double check that your browser supports using `vw` as a `font-size`: http://caniuse.com/#search=vw

Answer (score 0):

A similar solution to jazibobs, also using the vw height but with more "flowy" text. Currently the background will respond to pretty much any width however at narrow widths it doesn't really make much sense with the text. For this you could use media queries to possibly even hide the background at smaller widths or just set the text smaller.

https://jsfiddle.net/kzhzasot/

```
#headerimg{
    background: url(http://images.huffingtonpost.com/2016-06-25-1466835058-3172856-DKCWebDesignBanner.jpg) no-repeat top center fixed;
    background-size: 100% auto;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100vh;
}

.header{
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 50px;
    display: table;
}

h1 {
  display: table-cell;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```